# Item not properly updating in Custom listview adapter using viewholder

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewholder

I am working on **custom adapter** listview using viewholder.I am **Increasing** and **decreasing** the cart item using **+** and **-** butons here. When i am increasing the first item in the cart it was not displaying correct increment value in textview which i displaying there and it was not properly updating the incremented value.Hereby i am attaching the code please do some helpful.

```
public class OrderListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<CartDetail> retrieveItems;
    Context ctx;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public OrderListAdapter(Context ctx,
                            ArrayList<CartDetail> rideDetails) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.retrieveItems = rideDetails;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return retrieveItems.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return retrieveItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.order_cart_item, null);
        }
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvProductName = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tvproductname);

        viewHolder.tvNumber.setText(retrieveItems.get(position).getmQuantity());
        minteger = Integer.parseInt(retrieveItems.get(position).getmQuantity());
        viewHolder.btnDecrease.setTag(convertView);
        viewHolder.btnDecrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (minteger == 1) {
                    minteger = minteger - 0;
                    viewHolder.tvNumber.setText("" + minteger);

                } else {
                    minteger = minteger - 1;

                    View temp = (View) v.getTag();
                    strI = String.valueOf(minteger);
                    String value = retrieveItems.get(position).getmCart();
                    String productid = retrieveItems.get(position).getmProductId();
                    String itemTotal = retrieveItems.get(position).getmItemTotal();
                    String unitPrice = retrieveItems.get(position).getmUnitPrice();
                    Float intPrice = Float.parseFloat(unitPrice);
                    finalTotalProductAmount = intPrice * minteger;
                    TextView tv = (TextView)temp.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
                    tv.setText(""+minteger);
                    mTask = new ReduceCartItem(value, productid, itemTotal).execute();
                }
            }
        });
        viewHolder.btnIncrease.setTag(convertView);
        minteger1=Integer.parseInt(retrieveItems.get(position).getmQuantity());
        viewHolder.btnIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View temp = (View) v.getTag();

                minteger1 = minteger1+ 1;
                Log.e("integer",""+minteger1);
                strI = String.valueOf(minteger1);
                String value1 = retrieveItems.get(position).getmCartId();
                String productid1 = retrieveItems.get(position).getmProductId();
                String itemTotal1 = retrieveItems.get(position).getmItemTotal();
                String unitPrice1 = retrieveItems.get(position).getmUnitPrice();
                Float intPrice1 = Float.parseFloat(unitPrice1);
                finalTotalProductAmount = intPrice1 * minteger1;
                TextView tv = (TextView)temp.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
                tv.setText(""+minteger1);
                Log.e("posiiton", "" + retrieveItems.get(position).getmUnitPrice());
                mTask = new UpdateItemTask(value1, productid1, itemTotal1, viewHolder.tvTotalvalue).execute();
            }
        });

        strI = String.valueOf(minteger);
        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvProductName, tvProductID, tvUnitPrice, tvDiscount, tvTotal, tvUpdate, tvDelete, tvTotalvalue;
        ImageView imageView;
        EditText etQuantity;
        Button btnIncrease, btnDecrease;
        TextView tvNumber;

    }
}
```

Comment: follow this https://github.com/c3ph3us/examples/blob/master/VaultListAdapter.java

Comment: i tried but its having the same issue

Comment: can you provide code of this new UpdateItemTask.

Comment: i think you are getting same quanitiy  here minteger1=Integer.parseInt(retrieveItems.get(position).getmQuantity());